# Fetch fixed set of duplicate records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I want to fetch records from a table that contains duplicate records. I want the output to be like only two duplicate records from each set of duplicate records in overall record output set.

example-

| Name | Country |
| --- | --- |
| John | India |
| Mark | India |
| Chris | Russia |
| Feggy | England |
| Rain | Russia |
| Monesy | Russia |
| Bhumi | India |
| Peter | England |
| Bruice | England |
| Radhe | India |

Output should have only two duplicate set of records from all duplicate of similar type as we can see in output below the country is repeating only two times and it took only first two counters of duplicate records in final record set -

| Name | Country |
| --- | --- |
| John | India |
| Mark | India |
| Chris | Russia |
| Feggy | England |
| Rain | Russia |
| Peter | England |

Comment: What is the logic for which pair to show?

Comment: Logic is to get first two duplicate pair from all duplicate of similar type. Like in country India, first two are taken in final output

Comment: is it MySQL or SQL-Server, please add only valid RDBMS tags.

Comment: Which column(s) define what are the "first" two?  Keep in mind that SQL tables have no internal order.

Comment: Country column should be considered for first two

Comment: Why should it return John and Mark for India instead of Bhumi and John?

Comment: I am assuming that SQL server is storing the records in some order, then only first two are in the output. Please correct me if I am wrong and there is no order then return any two can work.

Comment: @PallaviSingh Yes, records are stored in order; but no SQL doesn't warranty any order except the one you ask with an `ORDER BY` clause. Databases don't either return entries in the order they are recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You can number the lines by the window and select only the first N.
Sorting should be chosen according to the business logic of the query.
For example:

```
 ;WITH numbered_name AS
 (
  SELECT *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Country ORDER BY t.Name) rn
    FROM table t
 )
 SELECT Name
      , Country
   FROM numbered_name
 WHERE rn <= 2
```